# How do I use ffmpeg to trim silence in a mp3 file?

Tags: ffmpeg

We need to trim silence from mp3 files and since we're already using ffmpeg to perform some conversions, we prefer to use it to do the trimming too.

Is this possible?  I can't find any reference about using ffmpeg to trim silence.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#silenceremove

Here is an example:

```
$ ffmpeg -hide_banner -i the_4_hour_work_week.wma  -af silenceremove=0:0:0:-1:5:-25dB the_4_hour_work_week.mp3
```

`0:0:0:-1:5:-25dB` means `start_periods:start_duration:start_threshold:stop_periods:stop_duration:stop_threshold`. So it will search for 5s of silence less than -25dB.

By the way, dB is case sensitive. Really. dB is the abbreviation for [Decibel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decibel).

Comment: This will reencode the file?

Comment: @VitalyZdanevich Yes it will need to decode the file, then re-encode it afterwards. Basically everytime to modify the audio itself you'd need to re-encode the file.

Comment: Please note that at least up to FFMPEG 4.4.1, `silenceremove` **does not** "trim" silence (I'm assuming "trim" means remove silence from beginning and/or end). Using the `stop_periods` functionality, especially with a negative value, will remove silence from anywhere in the file (what FFMPEG documentation calls "middle"). Theoretically `stop_periods` can be used to remove silence from the end of the file, but it all my tests I could never get satisfactory results. OTOH, using `start_periods` works fine. For removing from the end see https://superuser.com/q/1362176/10942