# How to trim silence only from beginning and end of mp3 files using FFMpeg?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, mp3

After investigating to find a solution to the problem, I ended up empty-handed.

I want a context menu option in Windows 10 so that whenever I right click on a MP3 file I have this option to trim silences from start and end of MP3 files. I don't want to remove silences from middle parts of audio files.

Can anyone please provide me with the appropriate command line of FFmpeg to remove silences only from beginning and end of MP3 files?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Something like this:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp3 -af "silenceremove=start_periods=1:start_duration=1:start_threshold=-60dB:detection=peak,aformat=dblp,areverse,silenceremove=start_periods=1:start_duration=1:start_threshold=-60dB:detection=peak,aformat=dblp,areverse" output.flac
```

You'll need to adjust both thresholds (`start_threshold`) and durations (`start_duration`) to your specific case.

Comment: This works amazingly, but could you explain the part of two codes + areverse? Is it basically scanning from the beginning of the audio, then reversing and scanning from the end?

Comment: Yes, because removing silence from end of audio is problematic in sense that you need to know where is end of audio before starting trimming silence. And silenceremove filter can not know end of audio before it actually reach it except if user was tasked to enter it somehow before filtering process.

Comment: what does durations setting do here? Could you give an example?

Comment: If duration of non-silence part after silence is more or exact 1 second (durations are set usually in seconds) than it will not be trimmed. Silence is detected using threshold parameter among other options like peak detection and window size. This way you can trim short burst of noises too. I have WIP patch for this filter, adding support for keeping some silence before and after trimming so it is more natural for listening.

Comment: What is "WIP patch"?

Comment: Work in progress code additions to silenceremove filter to extend its functionality.

Comment: This command is not working for me, any update on this?

Comment: In what way does it not work?

Comment: Doesn't work for me either, just results in a file with no audio inside it when I open it in Audacity.

Comment: Please note that using `areverse` loads the entire uncompressed audio data to memory. When using `areverse` twice it consumes twice that amount because it holds both buffers at once. The actual memory consumption is much larger than what one may expect considering file size - for example trimming a 50 MB WAV file that way consumes about 1.6 GB of RAM.

Comment: _silenceremove_ has a new feature that can cut silence from the end: http://underpop.online.fr/f/ffmpeg/help/silenceremove.htm.gz ➔ 

This did the trick for me: `ffmpeg -i in.mp3 -af "silenceremove=start_periods=1:start_threshold=-60dB:start_silence=1:stop_periods=1:stop_silence=1:detection=peak" out.mp3`

Comment: 2022 version, I got this message **Output file is empty, nothing was encoded (check -ss / -t / -frames parameters if used)**

Answer (score 7):

For me, the best option for do this work with an mp4 file is this filter:

```
ffmpeg -i INPUT.mp4 -af "areverse,atrim=start=0.2,silenceremove=start_periods=1:start_silence=0.1:start_threshold=0.02,areverse,atrim=start=0.2,silenceremove=start_periods=1:start_silence=0.1:start_threshold=0.02"
-acodec aac OUTPUT.mp4,
```

To understanding all filter parts:

- `areverse`: Reverse the entire audio.
- `atrim=start=0.2`: cut out the first 0.2s to avoid that possible hight stop recording noise in the ending of audio (remember that the audio was reversed).
- `silenceremove=start_periods=1:start_silence=0.1:start_threshold=0.02`: This part cut the end silence out.
- `areverse`: This part back the audio to original way.
- `atrim=start=0.2` Cut out the first 0.2s to avoid that possible hight noise in the beginning of audio
- `silenceremove=start_periods=1:start_silence=0.1:start_threshold=0.02"`: This part cut the beginning silence out

Comment: finally something that works... Thanks!!

Answer (score 6):

FWIW, while the original question specifically requests using FFmpeg, there is a tool called `mp3splt` which will trim silence (`-r`) without re-encoding the MP3. This leaves the original quality of your MP3 intact.

Comment: Sounds great! But I want to remove all the silences from the start and end of any mp3 file in spite of its length. Currently it seems that the gui program of mp3splt won't trim audio files less than 2 seconds. Can you give me a commandline that will trim all the silences from the start and end of any mp3 file even if the file is less than 2 seconds long? I also want to replace the original file instead of creating new mp3 files.

Comment: sample mp3 file to test: https://1drv.ms/u/s!Atv-gP4NyojQoGrC_EAICpOcWTP4

Comment: `mp3splt` man page states: _To trim using silence detection **we need to decode files**, so this option can be really  slow  if  used  with  big files_.

Comment: This option was still way faster for me than figuring out what encoder settings to use etc. with ffmpeg.  `mp3splt` easily accepts a directory as input and you can customize the trim settings.  I ended up using `mp3splt -r -p min=0.5 ./trimthese` which leaves half a second of silence at the beginning and end.  In less than an hour, it trimmed a folder containing about 20 four-hour long mp3 files.

Comment: I would also suggest having a look at [sox](https://digitalcardboard.com/blog/2009/08/25/the-sox-of-silence/), which I found very easy to adjust and customise (trimming example from the website: `sox in.wav out1.wav silence 1 0.1 1% -1 0.5 1%`)

Answer (score 2):

I tried, as [suggested in this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1364824/167207):

```
ffmpeg -i in.aac -af "silenceremove=1:start_duration=1:start_threshold=-50dB:detection=peak,aformat=dblp,areverse,silenceremove=start_periods=1:start_duration=1:start_threshold=-50dB:detection=peak,aformat=dblp,areverse" out.aac
```

... but this threw errors when the file type was not *.flac (`Error marking filters as finished` errors, not-enough-ram errors).

I got it working by doing:

```
ffmpeg -i in.aac -af silenceremove=start_periods=1:start_silence=0.1:start_threshold=-50dB,areverse,silenceremove=start_periods=1:start_silence=0.1:start_threshold=-50dB,areverse out.aac
```

Answer (score 2):

I tried all the answers with `ffmpeg` and `mp3split` and couldn't do it for my MP3 files. Finally I got the result by usig `sox`:

```
sox input.mp3 ./output.mp3 silence 1 0.1 0.1% reverse silence 1 0.1 0.1% reverse
```

I downloaded it from [here](https://www.videohelp.com/software?d=sox-14.4.0-libmad-libmp3lame.zip) because other sources didn't have [the lib for mp3s](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39049900/350384) and without it it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

My original wav was

[image]

And my requirement was to remove completely the silence from the beginning and the end. This ffmpeg command do it

```sh
ffmpeg -i /home/foo/input.wav  \
-af "areverse,atrim=start=0,silenceremove=start_periods=1:start_silence=0:start_threshold=0.02,areverse,atrim=start=0,silenceremove=start_periods=1:start_silence=0:start_threshold=0.02" \
/home/foo/OUT.WAV
```

The result was that the silence was removed :)

[image]